# ¿Hay un equivalente en español para "Bazillion"?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, español-neutral, solicitud-de-modismo

[Bazillion](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bazillion) es una expresión idiomática que, como indica el diccionario Merriam-Webster, significa:

> a huge, unspecified number
>
> - … it sold about a **bazillion** records in its first week. — Jancee Dunn and Chris Mundy, Rolling Stone, 23 Dec. 1993
> - Here is a chart of six garden stalwarts out of the **bazillions** of possibilities out there in the ornamental horticulture world. — Glenn Morris, Farmer's Almanac, 2010

A pesar de ser un numero grande no es *infinito*. Tampoco es *muchos* pues este adjetivo no recoge la vastedad del número.

¿Hay algún término (o modismo) en español que exprese "un número **MUY** grande (pero finito) de algo"?

Comment: En México hay una expresión vulgar: un chingo. Tropecientos es much mejor.

Comment: *Quichicientos* (o *quichicientos mil*, etc.) en Argentina.

Comment: @pablodf76, ponla como respuesta cuando tengas tiempo, por favor. Al fin y al cabo "tropecientos" es un adjetivo coloquial de **España** y Chorrocientos de **México y El Salvador**. No sé si daremos con una expresión para el español "neutral", pero "Quichicientos" no me parece menos válida que las otras.

Comment: En España se usa mucho _mogollón_

Answer (score 13):

Sí: **tropecientos**.

> [**tropecientos, tas**](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?w=tropecientos)
>
> De *tropel*, con la t. de *doscientos*, *trescientos*, etc.
>
> 1. adj. coloq. Esp. Designa un número muy elevado de personas o cosas. *He visto esa película tropecientas veces. Presentaron tropecientas firmas.* U. t. c. pron. *Éramos tropecientos para el puesto.*
> 2. adj. coloq. Esp. Antepuesto a un sustantivo, indica que lo designado por el nombre ocupa una posición indeterminada y muy elevada en una serie. *La tropecientas edición del festival.*

También puedes usar [**chorrocientos**](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?w=chorrocientos) o, simplemente, **muchísimos**.

Comment: En Colombia también se usa chorrocientos aunque la mayoría usará "un montón", "muchísimos".

Answer (score 9):

En Argentina un término común para esto es *[quichicientos](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/quichicientos)*, muchas veces compuesto (*quichicientos mil, quichicientos millones*, etc.). Hay varios [sinónimos](http://es.thefreedictionary.com/quichicientos) en la región, entre ellos (en Perú) el bastante similar *cuchucientos*. La palabra está bien atestiguada desde hace bastante tiempo (ver [un ejemplo](http://hay-cosas-peores.blogspot.com.ar/2007/09/quichicientos.html), [otro ejemplo](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=QfU8AgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA30&ots=AtpudmywuF&dq=quichicientos&pg=PA31#v=onepage&q=quichicientos&f=false), [otro más](https://www.facebook.com/ajoyagua45/posts/1806519756330540)). Nadie parece tener una idea clara de su etimología.