# ¿Qué es "poner las luces largas"?

Tags: modismos, expresiones, significado

El otro día, en un ejercicio casi de masoquismo, decidí intentar ponerme de nuevo al día con la situación política en Cataluña. Leyendo el [*tropecentésimo*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/21418/5481) artículo de "los empresarios blablabla" me encontré con una frase que decía

> Los empresarios del sector del gran consumo **ponen las luces largas** ante el problema catalán y han advertido este miércoles del riesgo a medio plazo que supone para la recuperación económica y del consumo en España.
>
> <sub>[fuente original](http://www.elmundo.es/economia/2017/10/25/59f055a0e2704ea70b8b4619.html)</sub>

En el coche hay luces "cortas" (de corta distancia) y las "largas" (de larga distancia). Por supuesto las largas sirven para ver más lejos, pero por cortesía y seguridad las quitas si viene otro conductor de frente. Debido a que las largas están pensadas para que las puedas activar/desactivar on facilidad a veces se usan también para hacer señales luminosas.

¿Qué es exactamente  **poner las luces largas** en este caso (o en general, con sentido figurado)? No me da la impresión de que los empresarios estén intentando "iluminar o ver más lejos", ya que el artículo precisamente cita la opinión de este colectivo con el sentido de que ellos vislumbran lo que puede suceder. No me parece tampoco que los empresarios estén intentando "hacer señales o avisos luminosos". ¿O sí? ¿O es que intentan "iluminar o ilustrar algo a alguien"?

¿Qué significa la expresión "poner las largas"?

Comment: Tomar distancia y mirar en perspectiva, más allá de lo inmediato.

Answer (score 7):

En efecto, esa expresión hace referencia a la acción de activar la luz de carretera en el vehículo, y su objetivo es precisamente el que tú apuntas: apreciar lo que hay más lejos.

Personalmente no había oído esta expresión en mi entorno, pero parece bastante obvio lo que significa. No sé si la noticia que has leído es esta que cito: http://www.elperiodico.com/es/opinion/20141021/proceso-catalunya-explicado-madrid-3621206
pero igualmente el propio autor, Carles Campuzano (PDECat), lo explica en el mismo párrafo:

> aconsejo a mis interlocutores poner las luces largas y mirar más allá de la coyuntura concreta y puntual [...]

Parece claro que tu ejemplo se refiere a dejar de tener una visión de corto o medio plazo en favor de una visión a largo plazo, que tenga en cuenta un futuro ulterior.

La interpretación entra más en política, que no es el tema, pero básicamente viene a decir (entiendo yo) que, para el autor, las empresas estuvieron pensando en que la independencia, de producirse, en ningún caso sería repentina y desde luego se vería venir mucho más claramente. Ante esta situación, parece que, aunque no se proclame, la situación de inestabilidad va a prolongarse lo suficientemente en el tiempo como para que contemplar traslados u otras opciones sea interesante (Esto es lo que diría el autor).

Answer (score 3):

Las luces largas, cuando se utilizan a ráfagas, también sirven para llamar la atención de otro coche o para dar advertencias ante posibles peligros: cuando el coche con el que interactúas ha hecho una maniobra rara, para ceder el paso a otro vehículo, o cuando más adelante en la carretera está la guardia civil :)

Por lo tanto, yo entendería dicha frase precisamente como eso, que las empresas están **dando la voz de alarma o una advertencia**.

Comment: Tal cual, me has quitado la respuesta de la boca.

Comment: Por el contexto yo diría que es más bien lo que proponen en las otras respuestas de ver a medio o largo plazo. Ademas que a esa acción suele llamársele "dar las largas" en lugar de "poner las largas".

Comment: La verdad es que los verbos dar y poner son tan ambiguos, y a veces los usamos tan indiscriminadamente, que quizás sea una situación en la que el redactor puso lo que mejor le pareció sin pararse a matizar.

Answer (score 1):

Supongo que la expresión puede significar *iluminar más el problema* (para analizarlo mejor, por ejemplo).  Esto se me ocurre por comparar con el inglés -- lo cual hago naturalmente porque el inglés es mi idioma principal actualmente.  "Putting on the brights" no es una frase hecha en el periodismo en EEUU, pero me sugiere la idea de poner luz de más Watts para ver algo mejor.

Dicho esto... la verdad, me parece más apta la explicación de FGSUZ, que es la interpretación que le dí a tu cita en un principio.

Comment: +1. Gracias. Me he permitido un pequeño _edit_ para que la respuesta suene más asertiva. En la versión anterior quedaba un poco entre comentario y respuesta.

Comment: @Diego - Como quieras, pero yo francamente no creo que mi idea sea correcta.  La puse para tener todas las posibilidades descritas aquí.

Answer (score 1):

If you had asked me to translate this into English

> Los empresarios del sector del gran consumo ponen las luces largas ante el problema catalán y han advertido este miércoles del riesgo a medio plazo que supone para la recuperación económica y del consumo en España.

Businesses [...] have highlighted the Catalan problem and warned this Wednesday about the medium term risk [...]

I do not think our word highlight has anything much to do with headlights which is what I understand *las luces largas* to be. Unfortunately I am not sure how to back-translate highlight into Spanish.

Comment: Gracias especiales por esta respuesta. Tenía mis dudas al publicar la pregunta, porque pensaba que podía ser algunas de las acepciones (obvias) que describo en la pregunta, y que por lo tanto era una pregunta trivial (y muy pobre en el stack en lo que a calidad respecta). Esta respuesta profundiza en la discusión sobre si el modismo significa "dar mayor visibilidad", "ilustrar/hacer algo más claro a alguien", "advertir", etc. Todas pueden funcionar en el contexto del artículo, pero querría ver la expresión usada en otro contexto.

Comment: Por cierto, "highlight" puede traducirse al español como subrayar (el "text *highlight* color" es unas de las funcionalidades básicas de un _rich text editor_) y sinónimos como recalcar, resaltar, dezstacar, etc.

Comment: Diego - Sí, yo iba a decir *resaltar*.  Encontraste varias buenas opciones para *highlight*.

Answer (score -3):

En otro contexto puede significar haber consumido sustancias estupefacientes (que dilatan las pupilas y de ahí la comparación con las luces de un coche, cortas normal, largas, "colocado").

Comment: ¿? En Andalucía es bastante común.